# UK Pensions for US citizens - is an IRS Form 8621 (PFIC) ever needed?

Tags: united-kingdom, taxes, us-citizens, pension

An American friend of mine, who's a permanent UK resident and currently sorting out their US tax return, has just come across a new term from [FATCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_Account_Tax_Compliance_Act) - [Passive Foreign Investment Company (PFIC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive_foreign_investment_company). Via [this article from some tax advisors](http://thunfinancial.com/why-americans-should-never-ever-own-shares-in-a-non-us-incorporated-mutual-fund/) (which may therefore not be entirely neutral), they're starting to wonder about their UK pension and this.

Are all UK pensions automatically counted as *qualified*, and therefore excluded from the need to fill out the PFIC-related form 8621 as part of a tax return? Or if it's only some UK pensions, how would my friend go about working out if their pensions count or not? (I think they've got something like a stakeholder one through their current work, something else from a previous one, and a SIPP...)

Answer (score 1):

PFIC has nothing to do with FATCA, and was there way way before FATCA.

PFIC is a real thing, and avoiding investing in funds/holding companies to avoid PFIC qualification is a very good advice.

Specifically with pensions you may also be dealing with foreign trusts, which is another can of worms.

Your friend should hire a US-licensed tax adviser who's familiar with the UK economy and terms.

BTW: Your friend should also familiarize themselves with [FBAR (Report of Foreign Bank and Financial Accounts)](https://www.irs.gov/businesses/small-businesses-self-employed/report-of-foreign-bank-and-financial-accounts-fbar)

Comment: The cost of a suitable tax advisor is what prompted me to offer to ask here!

Comment: @Gagravarr you'll get here what you paid for